# Can I make my custom pytorch modules behave differently when train() or eval() are called?

Tags: python, pytorch

According to the official documents, using `train()` or `eval()` will have effects on certain modules. However, now I wish to achieve a similar thing with my custom module, i.e. it does something when `train()` is turned on, and something different when `eval()` is turned on. How can I do this?

Comment: How I solved this problem was having 2 different versions of the same model class. In one `forward()` func you'll have the training logic and in another one, you'll have inference logic. I can show it through a code example if you'd like. It'd help if there's a specific model class you've built and the logic for your `train` and `eval` funcs.

Comment: @TrigonaMinima Thanks. A code example would be very helpful. I don't currently have a specific model class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can.

As you can see in the [source code](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/2912390662c3c50732add54c94ac9b98d17e1cba/torch/nn/modules/module.py#L1259-L1292), `eval()` and `train()` are basically changing a flag called `self.training` (note that it is called recursively):

```py
def train(self: T, mode: bool = True) -> T:
    self.training = mode
    for module in self.children():
        module.train(mode)
    return self

def eval(self: T) -> T:
    return self.train(False)
```

This flag is [available in every `nn.Module`](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/2912390662c3c50732add54c94ac9b98d17e1cba/torch/nn/modules/module.py#L212). If your custom module inherits this base class, then it is quite simple to achieve what you want:

```py
import torch.nn as nn


class MyCustomModule(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        # [...]

    def forward(self, x):
        if self.training:
            # train() -> training logic
        else:
            # eval()  -> inference logic
```